# Install gnome shell 3.32 in Debian buster?

Tags: debian, gnome

So am having troubles with the Gnome default file manager `nautilus` being annoyingly slow and searching online revealed that it's fixed in Gnome 3.32
I have Debian 10 (Buster) stable installed which comes with Gnome 3.30
I found on the [Debian Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gnome-shell) what looks to be a way to install [3.33.92-1](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnome-shell/gnome-shell_3.33.92-1.dsc) using `dget` which I don't know what it is and couldn't get it to work

```bsh
dget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnome-shell/gnome-shell_3.33.92-1.dsc
zsh: command not found: dget
```

So I tried to install it but no luck either

```bsh
~ ✹ ★ ᐅ  sudo apt install dget              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dget
```

I wonder if there's a `deb` package of Gnome 3.32 somewhere that I can install directly via `dpkg` but my Google-fu failed me on this one

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the bug in Nautilus, or in GNOME Shell, or in some other component?

Comment: I guess it's `Nautilus` but upgrading Gnome is the solution everyone is recommending

Comment: it looks like `dget` is available in the Debian `devscripts` package:  `apt install devscripts`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `devscripts` which provide `dget` command.

building the `gnome-shell-3.33` dependencies (the experimental version) on debian buster will fail with `build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied` error.

```
dget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnome-shell/gnome-shell_3.33.92-1.dsc
cd gnome-shell-3.33.92
mk-build-deps -ir 
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Comment: I'm trying it out, slow internet xD

Comment: Just downloaded the source apparently